# Using a string with single quotes in a table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to insert the following string, as written, into a table:

`'affinity mask', 0`

However I can't figure out how exactly I need to escape the quotes. It always wants to treat the `, 0` as a separate column.

How can I escape the comma properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to double-up apostrophes to embed them within a string, since they also serve as string delimiters:

```
INSERT dbo.table(column) VALUES('''affinity mask'',0');
```